# Securely store logins to import data from external api

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have a service that imports large amounts of data from an external api. Essentially we need to make the data searchable in ways that current api cannot support.

To retrieve data from api we need clients' username and password. So what I did was to put in the credentials in MongoDB (where all other data is stored), but I encrypted both the username and password with aes-256-cbc and with an encryption key. The encryption key is made available through Kubernetes secrets as a environment variable.

But the more senior developer complains about this approach. He claims that since the encryption key is available at process time, this is simply just security by obscurity and furthermore just hinders him and the other developers to properly debug this application should there be troubles with the credentials and the external api.

So my question is what other approach could I use instead mine?

Edit: this is how my current setup looks

```
 +--------+              
 | Client |              
 +--------+              
      |                  
   username              
   password              
      |                  
      v                  
   +-----+     +--------+
   |Mongo|<--->| My app |
   +-----+     +--------+
      |             ^    
   username         |    
   password         |    
      |             |    
      v             |    
+-------------+     |    
|External api |-----+    
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hashing` with `Salt` instead of inception to save a password securely.

Way:

- **Hashing** is not `obscurity` its a signecher a shadow of the data that can be compared instead of the original data.
- **Salt** introduces an additional data point that is used to test the signecher (User has the *password* the application the Hash *secret* and the DB has the *Salt*)

Here is a nice article explaining the approach:
https://ciphertrick.com/salt-hash-passwords-using-nodejs-crypto/

After that, I would suggest reading about `JWT` (JSON Web Token). This will allow you to generate a sort of passport of a user after the login.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Comment: No, hashing is not gonna work in this case. I need the username and password to fetch data from external api. So once I store the credentials, I need to reverse the process to communicate with other api.